# Twitter Streaming API error

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, phirehose

I have been using twitter streaming api for a month and it was working fine. But right now it encountered some issues. I am always getting an http status code 400. I am using php phirehose for implementing the user stream. Also am using Http version 1.1 for connecting the user stream. How can I get rid of this? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest version of Phirehose: we recommend you [get it from github](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose).

(There was a patch applied on Jan 16th, so maybe that was related; more importantly there was a patch applied April 23rd (due to a minor change on the Twitter servers) that we think would have affected everyone.)